# sending parameters from Angular2 to spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-services, angular2-directives

i have a web service in my controller that takes three string parameters.and it works fine (tested using Postman).and i have a form that's going to send thees parameters from angular2.Here's my controller:
    `@RestController
public class RegisterAPI {

```
@Autowired
RegisterMetier registerMetier;


@RequestMapping(value="/register",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void register(@RequestParam("userName") String userName,@RequestParam("password") String password,@RequestParam("email") String email){
        registerMetier.save(userName, email, password);
}`
```

now here's my typeScript code(service):
    `@Injectable()
export class AddThreshold {
  constructor (
    private http: Http
  ) {}
add(userName:any,password:any,email:any) {
    const body=JSON.stringify({ userName:userName, password:password,email:email  }); 
    console.log('9raaahom');
    const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers,withCredentials : true });
    return this.http.post(`http://localhost:8080/register`,body,options)
   .map((data:Response) => data.status);
  }`
And for my Component:
    `@Component({

```
moduleId: module.id,
selector: 'app-signup',
templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
providers: [AddThreshold],
styleUrls: ['./signup.component.scss']
```

})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {

```
    angular = false;
    x={};
    y={};
     constructor(
         private AddClass: AddThreshold
         ) {}
      ngOnInit()
      {
      }
      submit (userName:any,password:any,email:any)
     {
         console.log(userName);console.log(password);console.log(email);   

        this.AddClass.add(userName,password,email)
          .subscribe(data => console.log("here"+data));

         console.log("end add ")
         ;
     }
```

}
`

and my webPageComponent:
    `

## SB Admin BS 4 Angular2

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-underline input-lg" id="" placeholder="Email" #email >
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control input-underline input-lg" id="" placeholder="Password" #password>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control input-underline input-lg" id="" placeholder="Repeat Password">
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="btn rounded-btn" (click)="submit(userName.value,email.value,password.value)"  > Register </a>&nbsp;
            <a class="btn rounded-btn" [routerLink]="['/login']"> Log in </a>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

`

Comment: Error in console : Response {_body: "{"timestamp":1493049128213,"status":404,"error":"N…ssage":"No message available","path":"/register"}", status: 404, ok: false, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers…}
headers
:
Headers

Comment: you are getting a 404 error, check if the url contains a context path at the begining of the url

Comment: i'm getting now 400 error :POST http://localhost:8080/register 400 ().